# Combining two observables, skip first value emitted by one observable if it is null

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am listening to two observables. In all cases, I want to filter out when `obs2` is `null`.

Now, `obs1` can emit a `string` or a `null` value. I want to listen to all values of `obs1` except the case when its first emitted value is `null`.

I can probably use a `boolean` to check if it is `obs1`'s first emitted value, but I was wondering if there is an operator to filter the first value only? Any help would be appreciated.

```
        combineLatest([this.obs1$, this.obs2$]).pipe(
            // TODO: filter out first value of obs if it is null
            filter(([, obs2]) => obs2!= null),
        )
        .subscribe(([obs1, obs2]) => {
            // do something
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) operator provides the index as the second param, which can be used to determine if its the first emission or not.  In your case it sounds like you want to apply a `filter` to `obs1$` to prevent emitting the first emission if it's null.  The also, apply a filter on the `combineLatest` result whenever `obs2$` is null.

Something like this should work:

```js
combineLatest([
  this.obs1$.pipe(filter((obs1, i) => i>0 || !!obs1), 
  this.obs2$,
]).pipe(
  filter(([, obs2]) => !!obs2
).subscribe(([obs1, obs2]) => {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. Didn't know filter provided index as the second param. Thank you!